# Dataframe groupby certain column and repeat the row n times

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to get df_output from df_input in below code. It is basically repeating the row 2 times grouped by date column. Also repeated tag should be included.

```
import pandas as pd

df_input = pd.DataFrame( [
        ['01/01', '1', '10'],
        ['01/01', '2', '5'],
        ['01/02', '1', '9'],
        ['01/02', '2', '7'],
], columns=['date','type','value'])

df_output = pd.DataFrame( [
        ['01/01', '1', '10', '1'],
        ['01/01', '2', '5', '1'],
        ['01/01', '1', '10', '2'],
        ['01/01', '2', '5', '2'],

        ['01/02', '1', '9', '1'],
        ['01/02', '2', '7', '1'],
        ['01/02', '1', '9', '2'],
        ['01/02', '2', '7', '2'],
], columns=['date','type','value', 'repeat'])
print(df_output)
```

I thought about grouping by the date column above and repeat the rows n times, but could not find the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) per date, and [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
N = 2
out = (df_input
      .groupby(['date'], group_keys=False)
      .apply(lambda d: pd.concat([d]*N))
      )
```

output:

```
    date type value
0  01/01    1    10
1  01/01    2     5
0  01/01    1    10
1  01/01    2     5
2  01/02    1     9
3  01/02    2     7
2  01/02    1     9
3  01/02    2     7
```

With "repeat" column:

```
N = 2
out = (df_input
      .groupby(['date'], group_keys=False)
      .apply(lambda d: pd.concat([d.assign(repeat=n+1) for n in range(N)]))
      )
```

output:

```
    date type value  repeat
0  01/01    1    10       1
1  01/01    2     5       1
0  01/01    1    10       2
1  01/01    2     5       2
2  01/02    1     9       1
3  01/02    2     7       1
2  01/02    1     9       2
3  01/02    2     7       2
```

Comment: Many thanks. I edited the post questioning the repeat tag. Could you answer about that too?

Comment: @tompal18 sure, just add an `assign` and a list comprehension

Comment: You are amazing. I am so impressed. Can I ask if is there any website that I can learn the dataframe so I can be as advanced as you.

Comment: Not a joke: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/ the documentation is excellent